Without changing the html code, make blocks adaptive to the content. Only due to styles
The blue block can use different heights, it may also not be in the document. Under the blue block, the news block...
Without changing the html document. Is it possible, using styles, to make the blue block be the height of its content, and the news be pressed against the blue block or be at the level of the red one, in case the blue block is not in the html


div {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 200px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.b_1 {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
}

.b_2 {
  background: blue;
}

.Content {
  background: #0caa27;
  padding: 10px;
}
<div class='gl'>
  <div class='b_1'>Blok_1</div>
  <div class='b_2'>Blok_2</div>
  <div class='Content'>Content</div>
  <div class='News'>News</div>
</div>






A bit hacky but doable


div {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4,auto); /* 4 rows with auto height */
  align-content: start; /* make sure the rows are auto height*/
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 20px;
}

.b_1 {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  grid-row: span 3; /* take 3 rows */
  background: red;
}

.b_2 {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 2;
}
.News {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.Content {
  background: #0caa27;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 1;
}
<div class='gl'>
  <div class='b_1'>Blok_1</div>
  <div class='b_2'>Blok_2</div>
  <div class='Content'>Content</div>
  <div class='News'>News</div>
</div>




If you remove the blue block, the 'NEWS' block will be located in the center (vertically). It must be pressed to TOP. The red block can also take different heights.

That is, to make the blocks on the left and right behave as if they were divided into 2 columns. Each block can take its own height...

No, it’s not possible. To achieve your desired layout, your HTML requires a flex wrapper to combine .b_2 and .news. I have called this wrapper .sidebar.
.sidebar {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

<div class='b_1'>Blok_1</div>
<div class='content'>Content</div>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='b_2'>Blok_2</div>
  <div class='news'>News</div>
</div>

A snippet to demonstrate:


body {
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 2fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

.b_1, .b_2, .content, .news {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.b_1 {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
}

.b_2 {
  background: blue;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.content {
  background: #0caa27;
}
<div class='b_1'>Blok_1</div>
<div class='content'>Content</div>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='b_2'>Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2 Blok_2</div>
  <div class='news'>News</div>
</div>




All child blocks should be on the same level. I'm trying to find a solution in which the blocks will work as if they were divided into 2 columns in html. Only in my example, everything is on the same level...

That is, to make the blocks on the left and right behave as if they were divided into 2 columns. Each block can take its own height...
